# Change background/opacity video with CSS

Tags: html, css, video, colors

I have [here a video](http://lucasdebelder.be/test/index.html), but I wanted to give it some kind of color correction in CSS/HTML, like give it a little bit of a orange overlay. 
 I tried using these three background-color: `transparent; background-color: rgb(204,153,0); opacity 0.2:` on both of the sections that are connected with the video, but that didn't do anything. 
 So I was wondering if it's possible? Otherwise I will quickly give it some colors in AE.

Thanks!

Comment: you can add a div with background-color: rgb(204,153,0); opacity 0.2; and place it infront of the video :)

Comment: oh, nice that you found your answer, good luck further

Comment: If I add some `filter()` on your `#video-landing video { }`, it works... - Take a look: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Comment: yes and make sure it is `absolute` and the container is `relative`. check that fiddle as reference.

Answer (score 5):

Yes use

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
filter: grayscale(100%);
```

or

```
-webkit-filter: blur(5px); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
filter: blur(5px);
```

There are other filter effects like saturation etc. use these on your video image in your css.
This link should help.
[filter effects](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/)

Comment: Is there a javascript dom property for blur() ?